# MariaDB and trigger acting on the same table it has been triggered from

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I'm actually using Mysql + InnoDB and I just got caught by a very troublesome (at least for me) limitation: the trigger cannot act on the same table it was triggered from. Does this apply on MariaDB too? Does it make sense to migrate to MariaDB to overcame this?

Reading the documentation it is not mentioned but some users may address this further.
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/stored-programs-and-views/triggers/trigger-limitations/

Comment: why it is so hard to cover-up one shitty functionalty? 2016 and still waiting.... geeez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q: Does this apply on MariaDB too?**

**A:** Yes, the limitation applies in MariaDB as well.

This restriction is documented in the MySQL Reference Manual.

**"A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger."**

(All of the restrictions that apply to a Stored Function also apply to a Trigger.)

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

---

This same restriction is also documented in the MariaDB documentation:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/stored-programs-and-views/stored-functions/stored-function-limitations/

---

**Q: Does it make sense to migrate to MariaDB to overcame this?**

**A:** It may make sense to migrate to MariaDB, but not as a workaround to the issue you've discovered.

Comment: what about postgresql? does it has this limitation as well?

Comment: @DamianoBarbati: I don't believe Postgres has this same restriction; I believe there's a limit on recursion... if a an UPDATE fires a trigger that in turn issues another UPDATE against the same table... the trigger will be fired again, if that execution of the trigger also performs an UPDATE. (You might want to want to ask this question about Postgres in a separate question.) (I do know that Oracle has a similar restriction on FOR EACH ROW triggers; in Oracle, there's a workaround available that makes use of statement level triggers.)

Comment: @DamianoBarbati: I've done a lot of SQL, a lot of database, and I've not run across a case where I needed the ability to insert, update, or delete other rows within the same table that a FOR EACH ROW trigger is fired. (I'm wondering if you are needing to modify column values in the row the trigger was fired for, and rather than `SET NEW.col = `, you are attempting to perform an UPDATE. Nothing in your question suggests this is the case; but lots of the uninitiated run into this error when they use an `UPDATE` statement to perform an operation that should be done with a `SET NEW.col` statement.